# How can I get UTF-8 character from keyboard or remove it

Tags: java, character-encoding

I'm using the `Scanner` class as follows:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println(sc.nextLine());
```

It works ok, but if the input contains utf-8 characters the console cannot read them.

So how can I get utf-8 characters from the keyboard or set input without utf-8

Thanks so much.

Comment: Which OS are you using? If I had to guess, you're using Windows. The problem is likely one of the character set of your console.

Comment: Yes, Mark Rotteveel, I using Windows. 
I think cannot get VN language from keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Try specifying the encoding and locale:

```
Locale locale = new Locale("vi" , "VN");
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in, "UTF-8");
sc.useLocale(locale);
System.out.println(sc.nextLine());
```

Comment: This is likely not going to work, `System.in` already is a character stream, so if the console supported UTF-8, it would already have worked.

Comment: Thanks for your ardor Isma, I have tried that way a few days ago.

Comment: If C# is any indication, you need to somehow specifically configure the character set _of the console itself_.